# Prevent memory allocation for NULL references in java

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jvm

Team,

All we know is NULL reference will be going to take 4 bytes of heap memory in 32 bit machine.

Assume I have millions of objects for this below class, but only some of index are filled with valid objects. lets take the worst case which is one index is filled out of 255. So (1,000,000 * 254 * 4) bytes allocated for NULL references which is costly for 1GB RAM machine.

```
Class A{
  A [] arrayRef = new A [255];
}
```

***OR***

```
Class A{
  A ref1, ref2, ref3, ... ref255;
}
```

What is the use of any project; which is holding millions of NULL references and allocating 4 million bytes for that.

So

1. Is there a way in java/jvm to do lazy null reference memory creation? Means don't allocate memory for NULL references until it is assigned with valid object using `new` keyword?
2. Is this allocating memory for uninitialized references is common in all the languages like C, javascript? Any language is against this concept?

One more use case in terms of Map; Assume Map size has grown for ten million, and then shrinks to ten thousand during run time, So initialized Map Array size will remain as is with null references which is going to take memory; which can be optimized.

> Finally for all the down voters

**If NULL references doesn't require memory; then HashMap can always initialize with Array[Integer.MaxSize]; then do bucket look up without rehashing and collision due to masking**

**Update:**

It looks like Array needs ***sequential*** memory for its size before it get used. So most of the programming languages can't prevent allocating memory though we have NULL references in it.
But i didn't understand why is the same;  expected in-terms of class references also ??

Comment: This code looks disturbing.

Comment: That's not a particularly large amount of memory. Why aren't you using an array or one of the Java Collections?

Comment: @Gergely Bacso i didn't get what you mean by disturbing ..?

Comment: @GriffeyDog Assume if all the 100 objects gets initialized then (100 * 255 * 255 * 4), also note that it wont be 100 object, it will be more than 10000...

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar With disturbing he means that he is irritated to see 256 fields instead of one array.

Comment: @glglgl :) ok, if i want to initilaize only ref255, then i need array of 255 size and only [255] object is initialized, and rest are NULL, then that is the same behavior like before.

Comment: The behavior is the same, but the code is much simpler, more manageable.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Yes, but it looks nicer. For the case you mention, I already provided an answer.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Well, your question stated 100 objects, not 10000. Even at 10000, by your numbers it's only 10MB. Perhaps you could describe exactly what your application is actually trying to do. Premature optimization is, well, premature.

Comment: @GriffeyDog I just removed the use case, Could you please check if you can give some light to me ..?

Comment: @GergelyBacso i have removed the code, and rewritten my question. Could you please check on anything you can help here?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar So don't have null references, use a `Map` like glglgl suggested.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Ok, in terms of Map; My use case is something like Map size has grown for ten million, and then shrinks to ten thousand during run time, So initialized Map Array size will remain as is with null references which is going to take memory. why so needed?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Anything you can help here..?

Comment: All I can say is that you won't be able to get this _lazy_ behavior you want in Java.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok Thanks!!, let me see some other languages.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Well, if you delete entries, you won't put `null` in the respective slot, but you remove them from the map altogether. In this case, the `Map` has the chance to shrink again if needed. If it doesn't do so, you can always `.clone()` your map so that it has minimal memory usage.

Comment: Perhaps [Trove](https://bitbucket.org/robeden/trove/) has an efficient sparse array implementation you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use 256 fields at the first place. Instead, you should use an array.

In

```
class A
{
  A ref = new A[256];
}
```

the whole array is initialized to size 256 with all values set to `null`.

That's probably some bytes more, but that shouldn't hurt at all - it really shouldn't be a problem.

---

From here on, we can address your problem: if, by any chance, having 256 "empty" slots is indeed a problem, and you are sure that most of the time only a very small amount of these 256 slots is actually used, you can switch to a technique where you either use something like sparse arrays which you must implement yourself - or you just use a `Map<Integer, A>` where you map between the index and the slot.

You just have to take care that you deal with absent values in an appropriate way.

So you could do

```
class A
{
    Map<Integer, A> ref = new HashMap<>();
    void setValue(int idx, A value) {
        if(value==null) {
            ref.remove(idx);
        } else {
            ref.put(idx, value);
        }
    }
    A getValue(int idx) {
        return ref.get(idx);
    }
    Optional<A> getOptionalValue(int idx) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(ref.get(idx));
    }
}
```

But I could imagine that, unless you use *millions* of `A` objects, this approach would be worse in total.

To answer your additional questions:

The described one is about the only way I can think of to achieve this goal.

Especially, you cannot prevent that a reference allocates the memory it needs for holding any reference, even if it currently just holds a null reference.

This is quite common for most other languages, especially if you deal with the said concept of using an array. (And believe me, you *don't want* 256 separate fields, in no language.) But other (higher) languages as well have thigns like Java's `Map`, such as Python's `dict` where you can add key/value pairs which then can be retrieved again.

Comment: Thanks!! at least you are responded. But my problem is not solved. This enables more memory for NULL references if i have initialized only some those.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar 100 of your `A` object would take 100KB of memory, which is *0.005%* of the total RAM of a 10GB machine. The RAM usage is negligible. Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Thanks! but it is costly for 0.05% for 1GB RAM and it will be more than 100 objects. May be i will re phrase my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a List of references like

```
final List<A> refList = new ArrayList<A>();
```

This way you start with 0 references and as you add each reference the List grows as required.

Comment: Thanks!! but i want to know/maintian the radix/base of my reference/property which i have initilized , example if i want initialize 255th reference/property of the class, then using ArrayList/Array of 255th index will be initilised, and rest of array in arrayList will be NULL. Could you please tell me is there way i can avoid creating memory for NULL references in JVM? OR any other language is supporting that?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar You could create such a data structure but I suspect unless you have a very low memory device, it won't be worth the effort.  My 1 cents worth is that 250KB of PC memory is worth 1 cent and you should spend an appropriate amount of time optimising the memory usage.

Comment: It is worthy, if this is possible then HashMap can always initialize Array[Integer.MaxSize]; then do bucket look up without rehashing and collision due to masking.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar The HashMap can do this but unless you are very careful and only have a few entries it will use much more memory. HashMap uses close to 32 bytes per reference assuming the Integer is cached.  You only need 1/8th of the maximum capacity to be touched to end up using more memory instead of less.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar I don't understand your question.  Lookups don't alter the HashMap and collisions are handled via a linked list in Java 7 and a tree in Java 8.